# 2D array of ImageIcon's displays inconsistently and only partially in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to create a screen full of 16x16 floor tiles using ImageIcons, JLabels, and a JPanel. My issue is that whenever I try to display these tiles using a 2D array, - even when looping the drawing method repeatedly - they don't display entirely. Rather, they only display a few tiles as opposed to the full arrays worth. Furthermore, the number of displayed tiles changes each time I run the program!

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameTest {

    static BufferedImage buf;
    static JPanel panel;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createWindow();
        loadImage();
        showImage();
    }



    public static void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setTitle("Tester");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.setLayout(null);

    }




    public static void loadImage() {
        try {
            buf = ImageIO.read(new File("res/test.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
        }

    }

    public static void showImage() {

        final int[][] MAP =
                {
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
                };

        ImageIcon test = new ImageIcon(buf);

        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        System.out.println(test.getIconWidth());
        System.out.println(test.getIconHeight());

        JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[MAP.length][MAP[0].length];

        for (int r = 0; r < labelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < labelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                labelGrid[r][c] = new JLabel();
                labelGrid[r][c].setSize(test.getIconWidth(), test.getIconWidth());
                labelGrid[r][c].setLocation(test.getIconWidth() * r, test.getIconHeight() * c);
                labelGrid[r][c].setIcon(test);
                panel.add(labelGrid[r][c]);
            }
        }
        panel.revalidate();
    }

}
```

Here about what's normally printed:

[image: Running Code]

It seems that the program just gives up in displaying the images. However, note that the number of displayed images changes every time! Some times only five images may appear, other times 22.

When I try using a smaller map such as:,

```
final int[][] MAP =
                {
                        {1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1},
                        {1, 1, 1}
                };
```

the entire 3x3 grid of images will appear about half the time, only one or two images being displayed the other half.

What work around can be implemented to solve this problem?

**Computer specs:**

Windows 10

i8-8700

1080 ti

16gb ram

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);`  ... which will make `panel.revalidate()` redundant

Comment: If you don't want to use a layout manager, you may have better luck using a custom painting route

Comment: As far as the layout manager goes, `GridLayout` would probably be the best for this GUI. But in addition to the advice of @MadProgrammer, note that that setting the top level container visible, should be done **after** all the components have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is one of misunderstanding ... and welcome to my world

Using `panel.setLayout(null);` means you are taking full responsibility for the layout, which is fine, when you know what you are doing.

Compound that with calling `setVisible` before you've established the UI and using `revalidate` which is used to run a layout pass and you're setting yourself up for trouble.

Instead of `revalidate`, you should be using `repaint`, to trigger a new paint pass (note, in the normal course of events, you should use both when updating the the UI, but since you're no longer using a layout manager, you don't need `revalidate`)

Possibly a better solution is to use a custom painting route, for example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int[][] MAP
                = {
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
                };
        protected static Dimension GRID_SIZE = new Dimension(20, 20);
        private Rectangle buf; // This represents your image

        private Dimension preferredSize;
        public TestPane() {
            buf = new Rectangle(0, 0, GRID_SIZE.width, GRID_SIZE.height);

            int max = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                max = Math.max(max, MAP[row].length);
            }
            preferredSize = new Dimension(GRID_SIZE.width * MAP.length, GRID_SIZE.height * max);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return preferredSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < MAP[row].length; col++) {
                    int x = GRID_SIZE.width * row;
                    int y = GRID_SIZE.height * col;
                    Graphics2D translated = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
                    translated.translate(x, y);
                    translated.draw(buf);
                    translated.dispose();
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## `GridLayout`

Another option is to use `GridLayout`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int[][] MAP
                = {
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
                };
        protected static Dimension GRID_SIZE = new Dimension(20, 20);
        private BufferedImage buf; // This represents your image

        public TestPane() {
            int max = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                max = Math.max(max, MAP[row].length);
            }

            setLayout(new GridLayout(MAP.length, max));

            buf = makeBuffer();
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < MAP[row].length; col++) {
                    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buf)));
                }
            }
        }

        protected BufferedImage makeBuffer() {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(GRID_SIZE.width, GRID_SIZE.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, img.getWidth() - 1, img.getHeight() - 1);
            g2d.dispose();
            return img;
        }

    }
}
```

but this will resize the cells, which might not be desirable in which you could use a ...

## `GridBagLayout`

This will honour the preferred size of the components better and, based on the way it's currently configured, won't resize the components when the window size changes

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int[][] MAP
                = {
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
                };
        protected static Dimension GRID_SIZE = new Dimension(20, 20);
        private BufferedImage buf; // This represents your image

        public TestPane() {
            int max = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                max = Math.max(max, MAP[row].length);
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            buf = makeBuffer();
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < MAP.length; row++) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < MAP[row].length; col++) {
                    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buf)), gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                }
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
        }

        protected BufferedImage makeBuffer() {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(GRID_SIZE.width, GRID_SIZE.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, img.getWidth() - 1, img.getHeight() - 1);
            g2d.dispose();
            return img;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for not only the thorough answer, but also so much helpful knowledge! However, I have to ask - why did you add protected and static to many of the variables? In my testing it worked just fine without those modifiers.

Comment: First, they only make sense within the context of `TestPane`, I don't see any need for any other classes to be accessing/modifying them, second, they never change (or should never change), so they can be `static`, this saves a little bit of memory but states your intentions over how they should be used ;)